# What are these yellowish flecks?

Tags: pests

I have something on many of my plants. It started on the purple passion plant and I thought it was pollen coming from the flowers, but I also see it now on some other plants. When I google yellow spots or flecks, I keep getting articles on leaf yellowing, which isn't right. Additionally, I see no damage to the leaves, so it certainly could be  a pest like aphids, but I don't see them causing any damage.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am sorry to say that we need better quality pictures. I know it is hard to get up close and in focus but I can't tell what is the cause of the problem.  Can you post more pictures?

Comment: Do the "flecks" move?